# Jquery ui how to scale with hide to a certain point

Tags: jquery

How can I make the scale effect zoom back to a certain height and width instead of 0?
I tried

`$(element).hide("scale",{to:{width:600,height:500}},150);`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

> $("div").animate({width:"600", height:"500"},150);

http://jsfiddle.net/aQLD4/

Comment: wow I use animate all the time.. I completely forgot this can be achieved with animate. Thanks!